# Apexchart: Radar Chart - Problem with showing xaxis labels

Tags: jquery, ajax, apexcharts, radar-chart

I'm having some problems with the Radar Chart from Apexcharts. I defined my Chart like in the documentation [apexcharts.js - basic radar chart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/radar-charts/basic/), and there the x-axis labels are shown and in my version they aren't displayed. Does someone know how I can handle that? Here is my code:

```js
var options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Rating',
        data: [4.2, 4.8, 3.1, 3.8, 3.5, 2.9],
    }],
    chart: { toolbar: {
            show: false
        },
        height: 350,
        type: 'radar',
    },
    colors: ['#00b0db'],
    xaxis: {
        categories: ['Meals', 'Location', 'Price', 'Features', 'Ambiance', 'Service']
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        background: {
            enabled: true,
            borderRadius:2,
        }
    },

};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#radar-chart-categories"), options);
chart.render();
```

[Here a screenshot of my radar chart unfortunately without showing the x-axis labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0umtR.png)

Answer (score 0):

I created a codepen with your data and it looks like it works:

https://codepen.io/welante/pen/dyWqMZK

```
window.Apex = {
      tooltip: {
        theme: "dark",
        x: {
          formatter: function (val) {
            return val;
          }
        }
      }
    };
    
    var options = {
        series: [{
            name: 'Rating',
            data: [4.2, 4.8, 3.1, 3.8, 3.5, 2.9],
        }],
        chart: { toolbar: {
                show: false
            },
            height: 350,
            type: 'radar',
        },
        colors: ['#00b0db'],
        xaxis: {
            categories: ['Meals', 'Location', 'Price', 'Features', 'Ambiance', 'Service']
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            background: {
                enabled: true,
                borderRadius:2,
            }
        },
    
    };
    
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#radar-chart-categories"), options);
    chart.render();
```

Comment: As we see in the dark mode it works. But in the light mode it still doesn't. Also after setting the color of the xaxis labels to black. Changing fontSize, changes the fontSize in the dark theme (same for changing show from true to false), but the color doesn't work.

Code of x axis:
 xaxis: {
        categories: ['Meals', 'Location', 'Price', 'Features', 'Ambiance', 'Service'],
        labels: {
            show: true,
            style: {
                colors: ["#000000"],
                fontSize: "14px",
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
            },
        }
    },